# How do sequelize getter and setters work?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**Summary of question:** Conceptually, what are getters and setters and why would we use them?

Excerpt from http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/?highlight=getterMethods#getters-setters:

> It is possible to define 'object-property' getters and setter functions on your models, these can be used both for 'protecting' properties that map to database fields and for defining 'pseudo' properties.

1. What does it mean by 'protect'? Against what?
2. What are 'psuedo' properties?

I'm also struggling with the example code below. We appear to be setting 'title' twice. And what is the argument 'v'?

See below:

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
  title: {
    type     : Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  }
}, {

  getterMethods   : {
    title       : function()  { /* do your magic here and return something! */ },
    title_slug  : function()  { return slugify(this.title); }
  },

  setterMethods   : {
    title       : function(v) { /* do your magic with the input here! */ },
  }
});
```

**A concrete example instead of "do magic" would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> pseudo properties

Would be properties that, from the perspective of the user seems like regular properties of the object, but do not exist in the database. Take for example a user object that has first names and last name fields. You could then create a fullname setter:

```
var foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
    ..
}, {
    getterMethods: {
        fullName: function () {
            return this.getDataValue('firstName') + ' ' + this.getDataValue('lastName')
        }
    },
    setterMethods: {
        fullName: function (value) {
            var parts = value.split(' ')

            this.setDataValue('lastName', parts[parts.length-1])
            this.setDataValue('firstName', parts[0]) // this of course does not work if the user has several first names
        }
    }
})
```

When you have a user object you can simply do

```
console.log(user.fullName)
```

To see the user's full name. The getter is then being invoked behind the scenes.

Similarily, if you define a setter method for full name you could do

```
user.fullName = 'John Doe'
```

Which would then split the passed string into two parts and save them in first and last name. (see the simplified example above)

> Protect properties

@ahiipsa already provided a good example of this. Getters are called when you do user.toJSON(), so you can use getters to easily remove sensitive data before sending it to the user.

Comment: Jan, when I add a pseudo property to findAll options.attributes it fails and says that my pseudo property does not exist in the database. This makes sense to me, but I would assume that Sequelize would know this and handle it for me. Is this the intended behavior or is there a way to select psuedo properties? I guess right now every pseudo property is included by  default....

Comment: I was curious how Sequelize would handle asynchronous getters, so I tested it out, and it works great without any extra work. If you set a getter for full name like `fullName: async function () { ... }`, and then access the attribute with `user.fullName`, Sequelize will handle the generated promises correctly without you having to use `await` while accessing the attribute. Just though I would put that here in case anyone was interested.

Comment: It would be great to see this with the more object-oriented style of `User.getterMethods = function() { fullname: etc }`

Answer (score -1):

```
@Column({
type: DataType.STRING,
set : function (this: User, value: string) {
  this.setDataValue("password", cryptService.hashSync(value));
  }
})
password: string;

This is the snippet which is used to store hashed password in database in 
place of normal string.
```